# PeerJS implementation in Hybrid applications

Tags: meteor, webrtc, getusermedia, peerjs

I am using [peerjs](https://github.com/peers/peerjs) library for audio calling in my meteor application.

I am using the following line of code to get the user media:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}, function(stream) {
}
```

My question here is, what should I use if the application is run on mobile as hybrid app?

Comment: You don't need to do anything different

Comment: @Mikkel so the same code should work on IOS and Android after adding the microphone permission?

Comment: That's the idea of the hybrid apps, I have previously built an Android app using PeerJS

Comment: @Mikkel Thank you a lot for the confirmation, the question came to my mind while developing and got me worried about the later development. thanks again

Comment: @Mikkel I tried running the project to test the audio calling form both Android and IOS but it didn't work and nothing happening. When I searched I found that Crosswalk is used with peerjs in Android hybrid application. Have you used Crosswalk when implementing peerjs for android?